# Link PDF document from XML

Tags: html, css

I've come across existing XML documents which contain various electrical components as well as a few of their attributes. I'm trying to link the PDF document in the  so that when opening this file the user can click on a link and navigate to that PDF file without having to search for it in the file manager. Any insight would be helpful.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="sub.css" ?>
<row>
        <title>Miniature Circuit Breaker S201-C2</title>
        <standard>ABB</standard>
        <make>ABB Control</make>
        <item_code>VAL0185012</item_code>
        <vendor_code>2CDS 251 001 R0024</vendor_code>
        <language>EN</language>
        <url>http://www.abb.com</url>
        <linked_file url="EL38/WDS03765.pdf"/>
</row>
```

I'm currently using CSS to style the document:

```
row {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

title, standard, make, item_code, vendor_code, language, url {
    display: block;
}

title:before {
    content: "Title: ";
    color: green;
    font-weight: bold;
}
standard:before {
    content: "Standard: ";
    color: green;
    font-weight: bold;
}
make:before {
    content: "Make: ";
    color: green;
    font-weight: bold;
}
item_code:before {
    content: "Item Code: ";
    color: green;
    font-weight: bold;
}
vendor_code:before {
    content: "Vendor Code: ";
    color: green;
    font-weight: bold;
}
language:before {
    content: "Language: ";
    color: green;
    font-weight: bold;
}
url:before {
    content: "URL: ";
    color: green;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: I ended up using HTML to represent the contents of the XML file and threw out the idea of styling it via CSS.I managed to make the necessary changes to the XML document and used the online [XML to HTML converter](http://codebeautify.org/xml-to-html-converter#). From there the PDF file was not hyperlinked so I had to parse through the HTML as a txt file and modify all instances of the PDF file location name to be enclosed in an anchor tag for that PDF location.